# HttpHeaders got changed in spring5 changes causing API to fail 400

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate, multipart, spring-resttemplate

right now im migratingour spring application from 4 to 5.
I'm facing issue with particular on spring web module

spring-web-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar  to spring-web-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar

I noticed the changes in HttpHeaders class. In spring-web-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar

where HTTP Header was

```
public HttpHeaders() {
    this(new LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap<List<String>>(8, Locale.ENGLISH), false);
}
```

Now on Spring 5-
this is changed to

```
public HttpHeaders() {
    this(CollectionUtils.toMultiValueMap(new LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap<>(8, Locale.ENGLISH)));
}
```

Now header is changed from-
{Accept=[application/json], Content-Type=[multipart/form-data;boundary=8HFYfdj_y58sNxrSdXenwlIQDsYiXS50], Content-Length=[51024]}

to
[Accept:"application/json", Content-Type:"multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8;boundary=lqBw1IeG3PhU9oYKiHGbhABo2SWZ6lBR", Content-Length:"37353"]

I searched a lot found one similar issue
this seems some more closely relevant -
[Upgrading to Spring 5 broke RestTemplate MultipartFile upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51390193/upgrading-to-spring-5-broke-resttemplate-multipartfile-upload)

Do anyone have any Idea how to deal this.

Comment: You should upgrade everything to the same version not parts of the application!. Also what is the issue you are having? That isn't clear from the question.

Comment: Hi, @M.Deinum right now we upgraded to Spring 5.1.13.RELEASE . while we performing the test found that file upload is no more working. when looked deeper. found header is totally different now what we had before.Now the API respond 400.

Comment: Is it only the test that is failing or as well when you run the application and do the actual upload? ALso is there a reason you aren't using the latest 5.1.16 (or even 5.2.7) but an older release?

Comment: Actual upload as repose is 400 now. ya we cant change spring version. as this is extension based application (more specifically if I tell it is Hybris 1905) and we cant change its core spring  to 5.2.7. to just fix this

Answer (score 0):

Hi Found the solution.

when we looked at the raw request found some different thing

```
POST /XX/XXXX/XXXX HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8;boundary=3gOLqmQ6U7u3Iycd0lRnLnVa7dSIvAYqY7
Content-Length: 470
Host: localhost:XXXX
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/X.X.X (Java/11.0.X)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

--3gOLqmQ6U7u3Iycd0lRnLnVa7dSIvAYqY7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload_file"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 48

[{"key":"291c0f23-712e-43p3-aq47-51899270a415"}]
--3gOLqmQ6U7u3Iycd0lRnLnVa7dSIvAYqY7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="291c0f23-712e-43p3-aq47-51899270a415"; filename="291c0f23-712e-43p3-aq47-51899270a415"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 5


--3gOLqmQ6U7u3Iycd0lRnLnVa7dSIvAYqY7--
```

In the following Content-Type: application/octet-stream got added in our request. this confused the endpoint. previously in older version of spring resttemplate for upload_file there was no  Content-Type specified. now in newer version of spring this got added. Now we changed this to application/json. Now it is working fine.